# How to register AuthFeature from plugin?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to register AuthProvider from plugin.

```
public class Plugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
            }
        ));
        appHost.GetContainer().Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
        appHost.GetContainer().Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);
    }
}
```

Plugin is successfully loaded but when I open my endpoint in web browser I'm getting error:

```
The AuthService must be initialized by calling AuthService.Init to use an authenticate attribute
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins need to be registered **before they're loaded** which you can do in the constructor or by implementing the [IPreInitPlugin interface to run custom logic](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins#custom-logic-before-plugins-are-loaded) before the plugins are loaded, e.g:

```
public class Plugin : IPlugin, IPreInitPlugin
{
    public void Configure(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
            }
        ));
    }

    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.GetContainer().Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
        appHost.GetContainer().Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);
    }
}
```

An alternative API to load dependent plugins in the registration of a Plugin is to use the `LoadPlugin` API, e.g:

```
public class Plugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.GetContainer().Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
        appHost.GetContainer().Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);

        appHost.LoadPlugin(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this as suggested in this article: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services - search for comment: "Load dependent plugins"

Comment: @smokeing if you want to do that you need to call `LoadPlugin()` API as-is shown.